# Is it possible to use two different versions of a library in NPM?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, npm, yarnpkg

I have a large Vue.js app using Vuetify v1.5 I'd like to transition the app to 2.0. But, it would create many breaking changes, and we don't have time to rewrite all the components to support Vuetify 2.0. But, by using Vuetify 2.0 to build features from this point forward, we would have less work to do when we do go back and upgrade the 1.5 stuff.

Is this possible? Can anyone point me in the right direction here?

Answer (score 1):

Probably you can use [Module Alias](https://www.npmjs.com/package/module-alias) and use an alias for the second package.